# angularJS, after injecting service, it still reports unknow provider

Tags: angularjs

I have injected the new service into my controller, but it always says unknown provider

my code:
export service:

```
 class AlertService {
    constructor($rootScope,$injector) {
        this.rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.injector = $injector;
    }

    showAlert(alertTitle='Alert',alertBody='') {
        this.injector.get('$uibModal').open({
        template: '<header><div class="alert-header"><h1>' + alertTitle + '</h1></div><div class="alert-close" ng-click="ok()"><i class="icon icon--close" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></header>'
         + '<section class="content-section content-section-alert"><p>' + alertBody + '</p></section>'
         + '<footer><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">ok</button>',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance,$rootScope) {
            $rootScope.ok = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        },
        windowClass: 'alert-modal'
      });
    }
}

AlertService.$inject = ['$rootScope','$injector'];

export default angular.module('services.alertService', [])
    .service('alertService', AlertService)
    .name;
```

inject the service into controller:

```
    export default class StartController {
        constructor($scope, alertService, $location){
            this.alertService = alertService
            this.scope = $scope
            this.location = $location

            this.watchUrl()
        }

        watchUrl() {
           let url = this.location.url()
           if(url.indexOf('start') == -1)
              return

           this.alertService.showAlert('alert','some error')
        }
    }
StartController.$inject = ['$scope', 'alertService', '$location'];
```

it would always report unknown provider:

```
Unknown provider: tProvider <- t
```

if I change the `alertService` to `alert()`, then it works

what would be the reason? thanks

Comment: Presumably the problem is in `AlertService`. What does it look like?

Comment: Also, what module is your controller in? Does that module depend on `services.alertService`?

Comment: @Phil, I pasted the alertService code

Comment: And my other question? Also, why not simply inject `$uibModal` instead of fetching it from the injector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided dependency injection annotations for the modal's controller

```
controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $rootScope) { ... }
```

Either extract it to a function or class so you can set the `$inject` property or use the array annotation, eg

```
controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$rootScope', 
            function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $rootScope) { ... }]
```